# How to get a sub-string array from array string c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I'm new to c#.
I have a string that is split into string array and one of to elements needs to be split again into string array as its parsed differently. Then I'm trying to  convert the string arrays to float arrays and combine them together into one final float array with everyone at their original position.

```
string ido = "433, 045, 3-3-15, 444, 0.6,3.9,4,5,5,4,3,3"; 

string[] sn= ido.Split(',', 13, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string subnum = sn[2];
string[] st   = subnum.Split('-',3,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
float [] stNum = array.ConvertAll<string, float>(st, float.Parse)

float[] fArray = new float[ float.Parse(sn[0]), float.Parse(sn[1]),...
stNum, float.Parse(sn[3:end])];
```

I know this last line is wrong. I don't want to feed each element into the float.Parse() individually. I'm trying to Is there a better way to do this? I can use the ConvertAll but how do I just get the elements in the string array from element 3 to the end of the array?

Comment: Is the final desired output the following array of floats: `{433, 45, 3, 3, 15, 444, 0.6, 3.9, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3`? If so, you should be able to do something like this: `ido.Split(new [] { ',', '-' }).Select(float.Parse).ToArray()`.

Comment: What if you use a for to iterate trough the array?

Comment: You can use extension method `Skip` to skip the first 2 elements, it will return a new array (ToArray()) start with element 3.  
`var a = new[] { 1,2,3,4 };   a = a.Skip(2).ToArray();`

Comment: Thanks guys this helped!  I think the a.skip method is what I'm looking for but I will use the other methods to clean up my code.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want a result of an Array of floats, you can simply split your original string on both the `','` and `'-'` characters, so that you end up with an array of only "number strings". Then you can use `float.TryParse()` to convert each "number string" to a `float` and add them to your array.

```
private static void Main()
{
    string ido = "433, 045, 3-3-15, 444, 0.6,3.9,4,5,5,4,3,3";

    // Split on both comma and dash
    var items = ido.Split(',', '-');

    // This list will hold all the items converted to floats
    var result = new List<float>();

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        float temp;

        // Use TryParse to ensure we can successfully convert each item
        if (float.TryParse(item, out temp))
        {
            result.Add(temp);
        }
    }

    // Display final results
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
}
```

Ouput:

> 433, 45, 3, 3, 15, 444, 0.6, 3.9, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3

Note that in the example above I used a `List<float>` because if `TryParse` fails for any item in the original array, we won't add that item to the final result and therefore we don't know for certain how many items to initialize an array with. If you *really* need an array, you can always convert the list to an array by calling the `ToArray()` method like so:

```
float[] arrayResult = result.ToArray();
```

**UPDATE**

You can also shorten the whole thing down into a couple of lines if you're familiar with LINQ:

```
string ido = "433, 045, 3-3-15, 444, 0.6,3.9,4,5,5,4,3,3";

float temp = 0; // Temporarily holds each converted item

float[] arrayResult = ido.Split(',', '-')
    .Where(item => float.TryParse(item, out temp))
    .Select(item => temp)
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

This a bit verbose but I think it does what you need.

```
string ido = "433, 045, 3-3-15, 444, 0.6,3.9,4,5,5,4,3,3"; 

string[] sn= ido.Split(new char[]{','}, 13, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
foreach (string str in sn)
{
    string trimmedStr = str.Trim();
    float f;
    if (float.TryParse(trimmedStr, out f))
    {
        list.Add(f);
    }
    else if (trimmedStr.Contains("-"))
    {
        ArrayList list2 = new ArrayList();
        foreach (string str2 in trimmedStr.Split(new char[]{'-'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            string trimmedStr2 = str2.Trim();
            if (float.TryParse(trimmedStr2, out f))
            {
                list2.Add(f);
            }
        }
        list.Add(list2.ToArray());
    }
}

object[] array = list.ToArray();
```

Resulting in this:

[image: Results]